# What's wrong with my angularjs factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have a build an app

```
var HappySundayonEtsyApp = angular.module('HappySundayonEtsyApp', ['ngResource']);
```

with a controller like

```
HappySundayonEtsyApp.controller('ListingsController',
function ListingsController ($scope, $filter, Listings, $resource) {
$scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
...
```

The controller is working fine with some static JSON added in the controller for testing. When I try to get data with a service defined as

```
HappySundayonEtsyApp.factory('Listings', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
var resource = $resource('/listings/:id', { 
  id : '@id' 
}, {
  index : { method: 'GET', isArray : true },
  save : { method : 'PUT' }
});
return resource;
}]);
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.items = Listings.get()
```

nothing works. The URL delivers perfectly fine JSON as I verified with a simple

```
$http.get('/listings/').success(function(data){
   $scope.items = data;
});
```

In the debugger (Chrome) I see

```
Listings.get(): h
  __proto__: h
```

I am using version 1.0.3. I would really appreciate if somebody can help, I am deeply frustrated after reading, trying and debugging for 2 days. Probably it is something simple...

Thanks.

Comment: To what URL does the request goto? Try: `Listings.get({ id: '11' })` should generate a request to `/listings/11`

Comment: I had a look into it and yes, it generates a request 

    `/listings/11`

visible in the log of the Rails app serving REST. In the browser this returns proper JSON, the $scope.items is again

    `$scope.items: h
    __proto__: h$
    delete: function (a,b,f)
    {var g=d(this),e=p,j;switch(arguments.length)
    {case 3:g=a;e=b;j=f;break;case 2:case 1:r(a)?(e=a,j=b):
    ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `$resource`, calling the `.get` method doesn't return the response from the HTTP call, it just returns a promise of it. This means that $scope.items **WILL IN THE FUTURE** contain the result.

To be sure that `$scope.items` contains the response of the HTTP/$resource call assign $scope.items in the callback instead:

```
Listings.get(function (response) {
    $scope.items = response;
});
```

However, let's say you have this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use this: `$scope.items = Listings.get()` Due to that when the promise is fulfilled the repeat will be updated and iterate over all items.

Comment: Thanks, I read about the promise concept and tried it, didn't work as well. Maybe because I use `ng-repeat` - is there a difference to `data-ng-repeat`?

Comment: `ng-repeat` and `data-ng-repeat` is the same, `data-ng-repeat` is valid HTML and `ng-repeat` is not. But both work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks like your JSON is an array, and you specifically defined `index` action 
where you set `isArray : true`, so you probably meant to do:

```
$scope.items = Listings.index();
```

Comment: also, `index` might not be needed since **ngResource** provides a `query` method that does the same.